# How to get an ICopmpilationUnit from the current Editor in the screen - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, abstract-syntax-tree, helios

i ve been trying to get/create an ICompilationUnit from the source code shown in the Editor,
 i want to do that so i can later create an AST.
Can someone help me?
 thanx...

Answer (score 0):

try the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314208/writing-a-new-refactoring-plugin-for-eclipse). it might be a good start.