# Help with creation of refactoring plugins in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ide, refactoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a new refactoring plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314208/writing-a-new-refactoring-plugin-for-eclipse)

I'm looking for a way to add one or two refactorings to the Eclipse IDE (for Java code).

My idea was going to use some of the refactorings already available to implement my own although I am not sure this is entirely possible. I googled a bit but didn't find any info on which dependencies I must add to make my plugin capable of using Eclipse's already available refactoring classes.

If I'm able to use Eclipse's refactoring classes for my own purposes I won't even have to delve deep in Eclipse's AST stuff, which would definitively be a big plus.

Anyone has any info on this? Has anyone some experience in coming up with refactoring plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Unleashing the Power of Refactoring](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html).  It should tell you most of what you need to know.  Mostly you need the Eclipse Java Development Tools (JDT) and the Refactoring Language Toolkit (LTK).

Comment: Note that this article is currently marked to be *deprecated* (which does not mean it could not be a good intro).