# invert if statement in eclipse

Tags: if-statement, eclipse-cdt

I develop in C++.
I know JetBrain's function "invert if statement" to swap the if block with the else block and also swap the condition.
It there a way to do the same in eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with Eclipse through "quick fix" operation : select the if keyword and conditions then Ctrl+1 and select "Invert Conditions". Example here https://veerasundar.com/blog/2012/10/eclipse-refactoring-on-steroids/#4-invertingifstatement

Comment: At least with Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers in version 2019-09 this does not work.

Comment: My bad, I checked for java, not C/C++

Answer (score 0):

Not as part of the default *refactor* methods in Eclipse. You could try to write your own refactor plugin to add the functionality (look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1315990/3837873)), but that might be too much hassle.